# Unable to turn on debug for ADFv2 Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

Today, I'm not able to turn on debug on my ADFv2 mapping data flow. I'm getting the error below:
I already tried creating a new IR set to auto resolve and also set to same region as my ADFv2 - still no good.

> Failed to setup debug session. Error: No connection is available to service this operation: SETEX dfProd_dataflowdebugsession26a9d381-5924-4c1f-b36f-cf41e2eab60e_f96ba068-97be-478a-8ed6-012a7ec58d80; IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=100,Min=50,Max=100), WORKER: (Busy=7,Free=93,Min=50,Max=100), Local-CPU: n/a

Comment: Hi xichael21, Congratulations that your error solved now. I post this as the answer to make others know the error is gone. You can accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations that your error solved now.

I think maybe it's caused by the cache. Refresh the Data Factory and try again.

You tried again today and it worked.

I post this as the answer to make others know the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

What Azure Region is this factory in?

Comment: its in East US 2

Comment: I tried again today and it worked. Not sure what happened.